# Do I need RTOS implementation for this project?

Tags: arduino, embedded, esp32, rtos, arduino-esp32

I have three sensors reading operating thrice per one run. I am establishing connection with the sim carrier provider to make 4G connection to send data over the air. I am sending those sensor readings to the SIM carrier company's cloud database and routing that data to somewhere on AWS or Azure (most likely Azure). Meanwhile I am also operating buzzer and LEDs to let user know that device is ready, device has sent data to the cloud and so forth.

Now, in this case, do I need RTOS implementation for the task scheduling or any reason? Please feel free to leave as much information as you can.
Would you also please recommend, what are the other ways I can make this device complex? Or improve it?

FYI, we are taking three sensor reading for the redundancy. The program runs on Arduino IDE while utilizing Adafruit ESP32 hazzard MCU.

Comment: It kind of depends on how process-intensive the various peripherals are and how much of the work you can offload to DMA. If you have a big protocol stack on-chip then RTOS is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You don't **need** RTOS but I would recommend it. From your project description it is clear that you have 3 distinct tasks to perform:

1. Maintain a connection with the network provider and server
2. Read sensor data at specific intervals
3. Handle I/O devices for the user

RTOS allows you to run tasks dedicated to these functions and it will keep your code simple and easy to maintain. It will also allow you to easily add new functionality in the future should you need it.

Furthermore, RTOS already implements task notifications and queues, which you can use to exchange data between tasks (from sensor task to the server task for example).

There is an excellent series of tutorials made by Shawn Hymel available [here](https://www.digikey.in/en/maker/projects/introduction-to-rtos-solution-to-part-2-freertos/b3f84c9c9455439ca2dcb8ccfce9dec5).

Another caveat: The ESP32 runs FreeRTOS in the background anyway, so it's actually already running on you device. The question is just whether you want to use some of the features it provides.

Comment: Just wanted to emphasize the last point in Rohit's excellent answer. The Arduino loop on ESP32 is just another task in a full blown FreeRTOS environment, which is hidden from you so you wouldn't get confused :). Include the relevant headers and you're good to go writing your own application on top of FreeRTOS. If you're doing networking with cloud connections, those usually don't come easy on a bare metal environment anyway.